# foreach query in cypher to merge similar nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to figure out how to run through my database, collect nodes that are similar, and then merge them into a single node and re-direct the previous relationships to the newly created node. 
I basically created a bunch of nodes in which some or all of the properties had info, like this:

```
MERGE (company:Company{Name: 'Ford'})
MERGE (person:Person{Name: 'me'})
MERGE (car:Car{Make:'Ford', Model:'Aerostar', Color:'Blue', Transmission:'Auto'})
```

but I accidentally duplicated nodes that should have been merged, and instead created new nodes:

```
MERGE (car:Car{Make:'Ford', Model:'Aerostar', Color:'', Transmission:''})
MERGE (car:Car{Make:'Ford', Model:'Aerostar', Color:'Blue', Transmission:''})
MERGE (car:Car{Make:'Ford', Model:'Aerostar', Color:'Blue', Transmission:'Auto'})
MERGE (person)-[:drives]->(car)-[:parent_company]->(company)
```

so, what I want do do is take the three `(car)` nodes I accidentally created, merge all of their properties, delete the extra relationships created by extra nodes and correct the path, so `(me)` would only have a single `[:drives]` relationship connected to a single `(car)` connected by a single `[:parent_company]` relationship.

here is what I tried, but can't quite figure out:

```
MATCH p=(car:Car{Make:'Ford', Model:'Aerostar'})<-[:drives]-(person:Person{Name:'me'})
FOREACH (car in nodes (p) | SET Car.Color: 'Blue', Car.Transmission:'Auto')
/////This is where I'm stuck
```

**EDIT: Another Attempt(I get "r already declared error):**

```
START n = node(3) //node id for complete 'aerostar' node
WITH n
MATCH (company)<-[:parent_company]-(car:Car{Make:'Ford', Model:'Aerostar')<-[r:drives]-(person)
WITH n, company, r, car, person
MERGE (person)-[r]->(n)-[:parent_company]->(company)
DELETE car
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do this:

```
MATCH (car:Car{Make:'Ford', Model:'Aerostar'})<-[d:drives]-(person:Person{Name:'me'})
WITH car,d
SKIP 1
DELETE car,d
```

Answer (score 1):

[EDITED]

Does this work for you?

```
MATCH (car:Car{Make:'Ford', Model:'Aerostar'})<-[d:drives]-(person:Person{Name:'me'})
DELETE d, car
WITH person
CREATE (car:Car{Make:'Ford', Model:'Aerostar', Color:'Blue', Transmission:'Auto'})<-[d:drives]-(person);
```

Comment: unfortunately no, because the extra nodes(with their rels) still exist